# BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc00000bb when booting into Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I am running Ubuntu and Windows 10 on a MacBook Air. My installation process has been as follows:

1. Uninstall MacOS
2. Install Windows 10
3. Install Ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu from a bootable USB and just used the standard graphical installer and didn't change anything significant away from the default options. When I start the system Grub loads and displays a choice of Ubuntu and Windows ("Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1"). When I run Windows, it displays a black screen with `BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc00000bb` on it. I have `csrutil disable` active on my system. My partitions are as follows:

1. EFI (/dev/sda1) 210MB FAT "EFI System"
2. /dev/sda2 17MB "Microsoft Reserved"
3. WINDOWS (/dev/sda3) 29GB NTFS "Basic Data"
4. /dev/sda4 92GB Ext4 "Linux Filesystem" Mounted at file system root

I am using a GUID partition table. I have updated everything as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo update-grub
sudo update-grub2
```

and the problem persists.

I have tried trawling through various forums for help but none fix the problem. Any help would be awesome.